# ASP.NET Core route mapping: prefix is ignored

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I have a `.NET 6 ASP.net Core` web application where I want to configure all calls with a particular path prefix to map to a specific controller.

What I want is for all calls that are of the form `http://myhost/ipc/some_action` to invoke the action `some_action` of the controller `LocalIpcController`. Here's how I setup my route in `Startup` class:

```
//Configure routing
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    //Local IPC endpoint
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "Ipc",
        pattern: "ipc/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "LocalIpc" }
    );
}
```

However, it is not working. Specifically:

- If I make a call to `http://myhost/ipc/some_action` I get a 404 error
- If I make a call to `http://myhost/some_action` it works correctly

So it looks like the `/ipc` prefix in the path is completely ignored. Why is this happening?

PS: I know I can also use the `[Route]` attribute on the controller to do this, but I want to why it isn't working via `MapControllerRoute()` and what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you using `[ApiController]` attribute on the controllers?

Comment: @haldo: tried with and without but same result

Comment: @Master_T Did you ask why it should be working?

Comment: @Serge: sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: Was not able to reproduce. Can you post a full repro somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, I didn't understand properly how the routing attributes work in ASP.net.

In my controller, the action methods were marked like this:

```
[HttpGet("some_action")]
public IActionResult MyMethod()
{
}
```

I was under the impression that `"some_action"` would be appended to the path indicated in the configuration phase, to obtain `"ipc/some_action"`, but apparently that is not the case, the route specified in the attribute seems to override the one specified in the `MapControllerRoute()` method.

Answer (score 1):

I tested it out and it is working for me. Here is the pipeline configuration and the test controller:

```
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

// Don't forget to use the UseRouting middleware.
app.UseRouting();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints( endpoints => {
    //Local IPC endpoint
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "Ipc",
        pattern: "ipc/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "LocalIpc" }
    );
});
```

Note: do not forget to include the `app.UseRouting();`

```
public class LocalIpcController : ControllerBase
{
    public LocalIpcController()
    {
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Content("I'm here.");
    }
}
```

---

Also I would like to add, that defining the URL routes in endpoints middleware options is not in my opinion the best approach from readability perspective and I would use it only in some edge cases. It is much more clear to specify it in Route attribute (or you can even put it into HTTP method attribute constructor e.g. `[HttpGet("ipc/some_action")]`).

Comment: +1 because your comment about http method attributes made me realize the problem. In my controller the action methods were marked like this: [HttpGet("some_action")]. I was under the impression that that attribute would be interpreted as the "suffix" of the path, instead it seems like it overrides the entire path, so my mapping was being overridden.